# Undefined identifier "concept" in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio

the concept if supported in VS2022 and I can build it successful.

BUT:

the intellisense advice that "concept" and "requires" are undefined identifiers. So does the intellisense support the c++20?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you set the C++ Language Standard in the project configuration to C++20, and include `concepts` in the header file.

The following is my sample:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
concept Number = std::integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>;

template <typename T>
requires Number<T>
auto add(T a, T b) { return a + b; }

int main() {
  std::cout << add(2, 2) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

[image]